# jQuery event handling for HTML5 media events

Tags: jquery, html

I want to listen to some of the events fired by HTML5 `<audio>` element. Some of event attributes for `<audio>` element are : onplaying, onprogress, onseeked, onseeking etc.,

I tried to listen to these events in jquery using conventional `live()` function like below, but it didn't work.

```
        $('audio#voice').live('progress', function(){
            $('a#play').replaceWith("Playing...")
        });
```

I also tried with

```
        $('audio#voice').live('onprogress', function(){
            $('a#play').replaceWith("Playing...")
        });
```

Is there any other way I can listen to these HTML5 media events in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live() didn't work.  `bind()` worked.

```
$('audio#voice').bind('progress', function(){
  $('a#play').replaceWith("Playing...")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `live()` and `delegate()` for events that bubble. The audio events probably don't so you can only `bind()` them on existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to listen to onloadedmetadata, $('audio').bind('onloadedmetadata', function(){....});, but it was not working. At least for that I had to use 'loadedmetadata' in bind and then it worked. $('audio').bind('loadedmetadata', function(){....}); just a heads up for other events.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be helpful. I quote from the jQuery bind api doc:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.